# Prevent certain microsoft exchange emails from being pushed to iphone mail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

The problem is my work email is an exchange account and being at a large university there's a lot of listserv abuse (and I am not able to unsubscribe to these listservs). Specifically, I get sent calendar invites several times a day (6 so far today) for things like dissertation/thesis defenses for every student in the school. **I want to stop receiving notifications for a subset of calendar events based off sender and subject line rules.**

While I can add rules to filter these emails on the outlook website, it does not seem possible to permanently delete an email using rules (even the delete action sends mail to the deleted folder). At best I can move them into folders. But all folders get pushed to my iphone (including deleted) and I get a notification for all mail calendar invites regardless of the folder it's in (again including trash and spam).

One option is to stop syncing mail invites or turn off event notifications, but I tried that and immeditally missed a real meeting. The other option would be to selectively sync folders. But I tried this by going to settings>mail>accounts>fetch new data>exchange and selecting the folders to push, yet I still end up with all folders (even after deleting and re-adding the account). I don't see a way to be selective about which calendar events I get notifications for on the calendar side. I also considered adding a hook to isync that would immediately delete a folder after fetching but I don't think there's anyway I could do that before getting the notification on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm if you don't want to receive these mails? If so, could you have permission to open EAC? You could create a transport rule to block these mails, the rule for your reference:
[image]

If you don't have permission to access EAC, you also could create a inbox rule to permanently delete these meeting requests.

[image]

Comment: Deleting the emails is fine. It doesn't matter if they are deleted or just sent to a folder I won't open. I don't have nearly as many options as your showing. Whether that's because the university is restricting us or because I'm stuck using outlook.office.com, I don't know. But my only option is delete (which goes to the deleted folder) no permanent delete option. Probably just going to create my own work email and give that out like so many others have and ignore the university assigned one.

Comment: Based on my knowledge. you cannot permanently delete mails in OWA but you can do it in outlook client. Here's a similar thread for your reference: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108569/office-365-rule-to-permanently-delete-emails